# Wildcards in child_process spawn()?

Tags: node.js, exec, spawn

I want to execute a command like "doSomething ./myfiles/*.csv" with spawn in node.js. I want to use spawn instead of exec, because it is some kind of watch process and I need the stdout output.

I tried this

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn; 
spawn("doSomething", ["./myfiles/*.csv"]);
```

But then the wildcard *.csv will not interpreted.

Is it not possible to use wildcards when using spawn()? Are there other possibilities to solve this problem?

Thanks

Torben

Answer (score 10):

The `*` is being expanded by the shell, and for `child_process.spawn` the arguments are coming through as strings so will never get properly expanded. It's a limitation of `spawn`. You could try `child_process.exec` instead, it will allow the shell to expand any wildcards properly:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

var child = exec("doSomething ./myfiles/*.csv",function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    // Handle result
});
```

If you really need to use `spawn` for some reason perhaps you could consider expanding the wildcard file pattern yourself in Node with a lib like [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) before creating the child process?

### Update

In the Joyent Node core code we can observe an approach for invoking an arbitrary command in a shell via `spawn` while retaining full shell wildcard expansion:

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/937e2e351b2450cf1e9c4d8b3e1a4e2a2def58bb/lib/child_process.js#L589

And here's some pseudo code:

```
var child;
var cmd = "doSomething ./myfiles/*.csv";

if ('win32' === process.platform) {
    child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/s', '/c', '"' + cmd + '"'],{windowsVerbatimArguments:true} );
} else {
    child = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', cmd]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the simplest solution:

```
spawn("doSomething", ["./myfiles/*.csv"], { shell: true });
```

As @JamieBirch suggested in his comment, the key is telling `spawn()` to use the shell (`{ shell: true }`, [see the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)), so the wildcard is properly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? In Unix-family OSs (e.g. Linux, MacOS), programs expect the shell process to expand wildcard filename arguments and pass the expansion in `argv[]`. In Windows OSs, programs usually expect to have to expand wildcards themselves (though only if they're Windows-native programs; ported Unix-family programs may at most try to run the arguments through a compatibility layer).

Your syntax looks like it's for a Unix-family system. If so, then when you call `spawn()` you're bypassing shell expansion, and your child process is going to treat dots and asterisks in arguments literally. Try using `sh child_process` in place of `child_process` and see if you get better results.

Comment: Alternatively: pass in the `shell` option, e.g.: `spawn("doSomething", ["./myfiles/*.csv"], { shell: true })`

Comment: @JamieBirch nice catch there!