# Spawn SSH process (pty.js) and reading in local file

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, ssh, pty

Running a local file on a server is [pretty simple via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments). However, I'm having an issue when trying to perform this command using `spawn`'s argument array.

**For example, from the terminal this works fine:**

```
ssh user@host < some-local-file.sh
```

**But when trying with node, it instead attempts to look on the remote server for the file:**

```
pty.spawn('ssh', ['user@host', '< some-local-file.sh']); // Simplified.
```

Results in a "No such file or directory" error (looking on the remote server).

Could it be the way I'm formatting `'< some-local-file.sh'` in the array? I've also tried `'<', 'some-local-file.sh']` with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the < is a bash (shell) argument, not an ssh argument. try to call bash and pass ssh as a parameter: bash -c 'ssh .... < localfile'

Comment: It's throwing the same error. I thought it could be useful to not _force_ bash on the command by dropping `bash -c` or `bash -s`. So technically it could be /bin/bash or /bin/sh.

Comment: `<` is a shell special character. Its special meaning is lost when you pass it in as a command line argument. I suspect (since I don't know `node` very well — python `subprocess` has the boolean option `shell` for instance that determines whether command line is parsed by shell) what you're doing is equivalent to `ssh user@host '< some-local-file.sh'`, and in the second form, `ssh user@host '<' some-local-file.sh`, which of course won't work.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you think there is any workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: I feel this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21700422/4263296