# Wildcards in node child process

Tags: node.js, linux, child-process

So I would like to use a wildcard with a child_process, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
'use strict';

// child_process.spawnSync(command[, args][, options])
let cp = require('child_process');

let commands = {
    list:'ls',
};

let args = {
    details: '-la',
    path: '/home/music/*.mp3'
};

let worker = cp.spawnSync(commands.list, [args.details, args.path], {encoding : 'utf8'});

console.log(worker.stdout);
```

I would expect a list of all files in the directory that have that particular extension. I want to know if wildcards can be used in this manner.

Comment: Wildcards are expanded by the shell. You're not using the shell, you're executing `ls` directly, so no expansion is done.

Comment: you can try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717281/wildcards-in-child-process-spawn

Comment: now i understand essentially you need to run shell as the command and provide it ls

Comment: @melpomene what does `love` got to do with it?